# Is necessary add plugins for phonegap project?

Tags: phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

> Im totally beginner in phoneGap.  Therefore want to ask whether it is necessary to add plugins to the phonegap project :)? (when is relevant-> i use phonegapBuild for building my webApp)Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not necessary. You only add plugins you are going to use.